# Need to convert my code to spring enabled annotations

Tags: java, spring

I have a java project and test project which makes use of the code written in java project.
I need to convert my java code to spring enabled annotations and load them as auto wired spring beans in the test project.
Please guide me through this.

An example of java code in my java project is shown below

```
package javaproject;

public class JavaCodeImpl {

    public boolean clearData() {
        //some code written to clear the data
    }
    public String getVariable() {
         //some code written to get the variable value
    }
    public String getExpandedVariable() {
         //some code written to get the expanded variable value
    }

}
```

And below is my the code in my test project

```
package testProject;
import javaProject;
import org.junit;

public class testCodeTest {

@Before
public void setup() {
    JavaCodeImpl javaObj = new JavaCodeImpl();
}

@Test
public void testMethod() {

    Assert.assertEquals(true, javaObj.clearData());
    Assert.assertEquals("variable", javaObj.getVariable());
    Assert.assertEquals("expandedVariable", javaObj.getExpandedVariable());

}

}
```

Comment: I suggest you to start with some good spring tutorials. Best place to start would be: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ . Once you get the basics, you yourself would be able to solve your problems. Also, take a look at this book - [Spring Recipe](http://www.amazon.com/Spring-Recipes-A-Problem-Solution-Approach/dp/1590599799)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course you need to have a look on some Spring tutorial but just a quick description about what need to do in following steps :

**Step 1**

You need to use any out of these annotations (according to the functionality of you class) on your class `JavaCodeImpl` viz.

- @Component
- @Service
- @controller
- @Repository

so may be `@Service` in your case.

**Step 2**

You need to provide proper namespace in your configuration file and need to declare following

`<annotation-driven />`

to make sure Spring can interpret annotations.

**Step 3**

You need to provide following with proper package name:

`<context:component-scan base-package="javaproject" />`

so that Spring can find all annotated classes in specified package and declare beans for you automatically, while other alternate is to declare beans explicitly in you configuration file:

**Step 4**

Now you can autowire it as a bean in your class like

`@Autowired
JavaCodeImpl javaObject;`